# CSS обрезаный фон

Tags: css, css3, bootstrap

Здравствуйте, думал сам разобраться, но что то никак не получается. Проблема такова: имеется сайт с 3 фонами (в шапке одна картинка, вторая через весь сайт, и 3 в футере). В тех что в шапке и футере имеют плавный переход, но они обрезаны.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я использую Бутстрап, если что.

Comment: Может проблема в самой картинке? Плохо сохранили в `.png` формате в фотошопе?)

Comment: @Cactus нет, как я понял, проблема в том, что сам div маленький, а картинку оно размещает по нему (сама картинка больше чем div). Потому было принято решение, уменьшить саму картинку.

Comment: Покажите код пожалуйста.

Comment: если картинка - это background, задайте блоку свойство background-size: cover

Answer (score 1):

```
background-size: contain;
```

или

```
background-size: fill;
```

Смотря какого результата нужно добится.

`background-size: cover;` - не поможет, так как она и так обрезается по длинной стороне